# Editing the "video link" of a Google Calendar invitation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-hangouts

I'm currently using AppScripts to create a Calendar Invitation via Sheets. However, I can't see to find how I can change the `HangoutID` (Video Link) object field. It currently seems to default to the name of the invitee.

Has anyone experienced this before? Is there a method to call to edit the video link in Apps Script? Or is there some other Google API that can be used to modify this property?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share an example of the resource you get back? Where is the event "held", e.g. a Google+ Page/User, created in Calendar, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**hangoutLink** is not '`writable`' which means you can't change it.

You can see all the calendar properties which are mutable in this [File resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) page.